# How to list down products with images stored on server in android

Tags: android, json, image, android-asynctask

I am using AsyncTask to fetch the product the product list. It is returning a JSON Array of products including name, price and image path. These images are stored on the web server. I am iterating over the JSON Array to create the structure containing a LinearLayout as parent and one ImageView and two TextView as its children. How can I show the image of each row which is dynamically created using the image path fetch from JSON?

I have tried downloading the images using the path using second AsyncTask and passing that image path into it. I am successful in fetching the image but when I am setting the image in ImageView of the product row, the linearlayout is only showing the ImageView with the downloaded image and that too, the last image of the list. All other LinearLayouts are getting hidden or getting overwritten. I am afraid I lost the code which I could have shared with you for your reviews, but can you suggest me how to list product with images in ImageView or in background of LinearLayout when images are stored on web server?

Comment: try glide for images, try recycler view for list. I still dont understand the concept of lineae layout to show the list of data from server

Answer (score 1):

your question is not clear, but if your problem is downloading image and display it in image view, there is a third party library called   [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and its easy to use.

on your situation you don't need to use "second AsyncTask".

**Picasso** did that in **One line of code**:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```